# Custom WP_Query not working as intended

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a custom WP_Query but the results are not right.

I want to do is create a custom form to filter the Jobs registered with "WP Job Manager" using radius search.

This is my query:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'    => 'job_listing',
'post_status'  => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'geolocation_long',
                'value'   => array($maxLong,$minLong),
                'compare' => 'between',
                'type'      => 'numeric',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'geolocation_lat',
                'value'   => array($maxLat,$minLat),
                'compare' => 'between',
                'type'      => 'numeric',
            ),
        ),
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Can you spot any issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get? That will surely be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: I'd agree with what @nyedidikeke said, as well as providing what a var_dump of $maxLong, $minLong are. It might be a variable type problem. Additionally, the documentation specifies that the compare "BETWEEN" and type "NUMERIC" be in all caps, although I really have no idea if that matters at all. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Well I don't get any error, it doesn't show any result, although, I checked on the database and it should give 5 results. @GregBurkett I've tried that but isn't working either. $maxLong, $minLong etc are just coordinates like 51.509865 and -0.118092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a problem with the compare `BETWEEN` feature. I would suggest you have a look at the exact query being generated and whether the compare is actually comparing *floats*, not *strings* (which might produce unexpected results).

Have a look at the troubleshooting done for a very similar query over on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/meta-query-using-between-with-floats-and-or-casting-to-decimal).

The following is quoted from the question:

> Since postmeta values are stored as strings, I figured I should be     casting to DECIMAL, but it just seems to trim the decimal value from the string due to the lack of DECIMAL arguments/precision parameters.

and review [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst)'s answer:

You can filter generated SQL and add precision parameters that you need.

Enable filters for `get_posts()` by adding following to query:

```
'suppress_filters' => false,
```

And:

```
add_filter('get_meta_sql','cast_decimal_precision');

function cast_decimal_precision( $array ) {

    $array['where'] = str_replace('DECIMAL','DECIMAL(10,3)',$array['where']);

    return $array;
}
```

Notice OP's comment on this suggestion too though:

> tried both solutions and it looks like it compares them as strings with single quotes (wp 3.1.1), any ideas on that? trying raw sql did work though.

Please update your question with further findings to enable us to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry I didn't see that question when I was searching for issues like this!

Anyway, enabling the filter and inserting the filter to cast decimal precision solved my issue! Thank you a lot mate!

Comment: @PedroPinto no problem, happy to help! Thanks for accepting this answer :).

Answer (score 0):

change $minlong and $maxlong

```
$args = array(
'post_type'    => 'job_listing',
'post_status'  => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'geolocation_long',
                'value'   => array($minLong,$maxLong),
                'compare' => 'between',
                'type'      => 'numeric',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'geolocation_lat',
                'value'   => array($minLat,$maxLat),
                'compare' => 'between',
                'type'      => 'numeric',
            ),
        ),
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, well this didn't do the trick but you were right! I needed to change those values, they were in the wrong order! Thank you